# How to get result from output of execute immediate statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

The procedue is only executing the below output but I am trying to get result from output of execute immediate statement.

Current OutPut :

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

select 'PRJA' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from PRJA.TableX UNION ALL 
select 'PRJB' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from PRJB.TableX UNION ALL 
select 'PRJC' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from PRJC.TableX UNION ALL 
select 'PRJD' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from PRJD.TableX;
```

I am expecting the result above select / output :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

Declare
TYPE T IS TABLE OF MYTABLE.ID%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
MYROW T;
v_sql varchar2(500);
v_sql2 varchar2(500);
v_prj_id varchar2(4000):='PRJA,PRJB,PRJC,PRJD';

BEGIN

 FOR i IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_prj_id, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
         FROM dual 
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_prj_id, ',') + 1 
 ) LOOP


   v_sql :=  v_sql || 'select '''|| i.l ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ' 
  || i.l || '.TableX UNION ALL ' || chr(10) ;

  END LOOP;

   v_sql2 :=  RTRIM(v_sql, 'UNION ALL ' || chr(10) ) || ';';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 BULK COLLECT INTO MYROW;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MYROW.XXX);
   END;
      /
```

Comment: did you try set serveroutput on

Comment: @Andrew yes. its also listed in the top of my query.

Comment: try to use v_sql2 :=  RTRIM(v_sql, 'UNION ALL ' || chr(10) ) || ';';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 BULK COLLECT INTO MYROW;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MYROW.XXX); inside for loop                                             because you want to print the result of this select query and not the select query itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two glaring problems:

1. The projection of the target collection doesn't match the projection of the dynamic query. They must have the same number (and datatype) of columns.
2. The `dbms_output` statement will fail because MYROW is a collection, and `put_line()` only takes scalar values.

There is also the clumsiness of the loop which assembles the query. We can use PL/SQL collections to make it tidier.

```
declare
  -- record type to match projection of required output
  type r is record (
   prj_id        varchar2(30)
   , event       PRJA.TableX.event%type
   , email       PRJA.TableX.email%type
   , modified_by PRJA.TableX.modified_by%type
   , modified    PRJA.TableX.modified%type
  );

  TYPE T IS TABLE OF R;
  MYROWS T; -- plural because it's a table not a record variable

  v_sql       varchar2(32767);

  -- collection of schemas to query ...
  v_prj_ids sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('PRJA','PRJB','PRJC','PRJD');

BEGIN

  FOR i IN 1 .. v_prj_ids.count() LOOP

  if i > 1 then
    v_sql := v_sql || chr(10) || ' UNION ALL ' || chr(10)
  end if

  v_sql :=  v_sql || 'select '''|| v_prj_ids(i) ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ' 
  || v_prj_ids(i) || '.TableX ' ;

  END LOOP;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 BULK COLLECT INTO MYROWS;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' number of records =' || MYROWS.count());

END;
/
```

Caution: not tested because I don't have access to a multi-user environment

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `MYROW` is of type `T` which is `TABLE OF MYTABLE.ID%TYPE` so It will be able to hold only one value per record of data type which is the same as the data type of `MYTABLE.ID`.

In your code, you are fetching `"PRJ_ID", EVENT, email, modified_by, modified` (5) columns and trying to assign it to `MYROW` which can not hold this much of column.

You must remove all the columns except "PRJ_ID" from your select clause if you are only interested in the `PRJ_ID` field.

something like:

```
V_SQL := V_SQL
         || 'select ''' || I.L
         || ''' AS "PRJ_ID" ' -- , EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from
         || I.L || '.TableX UNION ALL '|| CHR(10);
```

If you want all the data then you need to create the object which can hold the proper attributes. see this [forum](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9538235800346520561) for implementing a table of an object.

Cheers!!